# Responsive 2-column CSS layout including sidebar with fixed width?

Tags: html, css, layout, fluid-layout

Cannot find a solution for this (what I'm guessing must be a pretty common problem) anywhere.

I am creating a responsive design with a sidebar, where the sidebar needs to have a fixed width of 200px and has unknown height. How can I make it so the main content area takes up all the remaining width, without anything misbehaving.

The closest I've come to it is the following, but the problem with it is that the sidebar can overlap the footer. Can anyone suggest a fix for my code, or share with me some code that works?

```
            * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            outline: 0;
            -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }
        body {
            background: orange;
        }
        #container {
            max-width: 1000px;
            min-width: 768px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: yellow;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #header {
            background: purple;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        #main {
            position: relative;
        }
        aside {
            background: blue;
            width: 200px;
            color: white;

            position: absolute;
            top: 0;

            /* change this to "right: 0;" if you want the aside on the right. Also, change the "margin-left" code, below. */
            left: 0;

            padding-top: 20px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;

            padding-left: 10px; /* If you change this value, remember to change the margin-left value of #primary */
            padding-right: 10px; /* ditto */
        }
        #primary {
            background: red;

            /* change this to margin-right if you want the aside on the right. Also change the "left" code, above. */
            margin-left: 220px; /* aside_width + aside_left_padding + aside_right_padding = 200px + 10px + 10px */
            padding: 1em; /* whatever */
        }
        #footer {
            background: green;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }

        <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>LAYOUT TEST #2</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="primary">
                <h2>THIS IS THE MAIN CONTENT ** THIS IS THE MAIN CONTENT ** THIS IS THE MAIN CONTENT</h2>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <h2>sub heading</h2>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <h2>sub heading</h2>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <aside>
                <h3>navigation (left)</h3>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
                <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            </aside>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <h1>LAYOUT TEST #2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Long live `calc()` =) http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/CjWbv/

Comment: Whatever you do, you MUST create it with flexbox first and then create a fallback for stupid browsers.

Comment: With flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/CjWbv/2/ works in Chrome 25 but according to MDN: "Gecko implementation is unprefixed but behind a preference" (in about:config, very strange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the approach with all those `position: absolute` is not the best one.

1. You want to have a container element with a `max-width` and `margin: 0 auto`. Not sure why you might want a `min-width` as well; you can of course.
2. Any block element that you put automatically takes all the `width` of the parent element. Hence, there's no problem with the **header** and **footer**, just position them in the right spot and they will render properly.
3. As you correctly did, use a container element for your main section. Since the elements are rendered left to right, you might want to write the `aside` before the `#primary`.
4. Apply `float: left` to the `aside` with your desired fixed-width.
5. The main content `#primary` element will take the remaining space automatically (or just apply `width: auto`. **Note:** the *remaining space* is the remaining space of the parent element, so, if you set the `min-width` on the parent element, don't expect your `#primary` to be narrower!
6. Now you will have a problem: the container element `#main` will not get the proper height. [**That's because of an issue with `float`**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/). To force a parent element to get to the height of its floated children, use `overflow: hidden`.

You should be ready to go. Here is a [slightly modified version of your code](http://jsbin.com/eninax/1).

Comment: That's nasty. You're using implicit overflow to change `#main`'s content position. That'll get out of hand fast.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'll be happy to remove/edit my answer if there is something nasty; but as in the article I pointed out, there are other solutions to wrap the floating content of an element as well. The `overflow` one being the easiest and fastest; and I never had any problem.

Comment: Don't remove your answer. It's a valid answer. It's nasty though, because now your `#primary` is 1000px wide, while actually you want it to be 800px wide (which is how it looks). "How it looks" should be how it is, I think. If you assume #primary has the correct dimensions, you might make mistakes later on. That's why (I think!) it's nasty. With calc() and flexbox, the visual dimensions are real/actual.

Comment: Ah well! Of course `flexbox` is the exact solution to address this problem; unfortunately the browser support is yet too scarce to be fit for production, methinks. You will have to rely on some kind of fallback anyway. And it is probably going to be something like this or javascript.

Comment: Yeah =( 4 years they've been working on flexbox. Amazing. I still prefer your method over JS. You'd think there was a correct method with good support to do this...

Comment: Alas the evolution of web standards has been painstakingly slow, especially due to *someone* ** cough ** …IE… ** cough **. Hopefully with the aggressive upgrade policy that browsers are adopting web standards will move at a faster pace to meet the needs of the industry (I especially like the Chrome, who doesn't even ask you if you want to update; which usually I would consider a very bad thing, but in web browser it's about time!)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It's simple and seems to work. Even though it may not be perfect, I think it is more appropriate than flexbox or calc() right now.

Answer (score 8):

1 = With flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/CjWbv/2/

```
#main {
    display: flex;
}
#primary {
    background: #bbb;
    flex: 1;
}
aside {
    background: #ddd;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
}
```

2 = with `calc()`: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/CjWbv/

```
#main:after { clearfix here }
#primary {
    float: left;
    background: #bbb;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
aside {
    background: #ddd;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Both will require a fallback for older browsers (and vendor prefixing). Take your pick from the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Until we get flexbox, I believe the best way to do what you are looking for is to simply use the css `display: table;`. You will need to set the container to `display: table;`, and then each of the columns, just set to `display: table-cell;`. This will eliminate the need for using floats or any other JS magic. Also, this works back to IE8. I know it feels sketchy using anything with the word "table" for layout, but just give it a try.

[Check out this link for more info.](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout)

[Here is an updated version of your code.](http://jsbin.com/kaqixedi/1)

**EDIT: example code**

**html:** Assuming this markup

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
#main {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    /* no need to specify width. 
     * width will auto fill remaining width of parent `table` #main.
     * so 100% - 200px */
}
```

Comment: We have Flexbox... Only IE 9 that still matters doesn't have Flexbox. Love this solution though. Super simple. If only you added the code in the answer.

Comment: Although using tables for layout is frowned upon, this isn't really using tables :P so it's a very nice solution

Answer (score 0):

```
#main { position: relative; overflow:hidden;}
```

This stops the sidebar misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with adding `margin-bottom: FOOTER_HEIGHT` to the `aside` or use the following method instead:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        YOUR_HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            YOUR_SIDE_BAR_CONTENT
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            YOUR_CONTENT
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        YOUR_FOOTER
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    width: ...;
    height: ...;
    float: right;
}
#main {
    margin-right: WIDTH_OF_SIDE_BAR;
}
#body > br {
    clear: both;
}
```