# Fixed + Fluid layout

Tags: responsive-design

How do I create a 2 column layout, with 1 column fixed width, and the other column taking up the remaining space?

[Please see this demo](http://www.doig.com.au/test/2/).

Originally, I tried a fluid layout, but didn't like the left column becoming too small, so I wanted to keep it at a constant width.

I tried [setting the 2nd column's margin-left equal to the width of the first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437201/responsive-2-column-css-layout-including-sidebar-with-fixed-width), but this meant the 2nd column did not expand into all the available space.  It took up only as much space as needed, which was not enough to keep the layout attractive.

How can I make the #right column fill all the left over space within #container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is `display:table`. It's perhaps not the best way, but it works. You can see a fiddle I created with your code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hp8Vg/1/

You could also use calc() in your CSS, but that is not as widely supported.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I want to keep #container at 960px, and #footer also.

Comment: Well then you don't really want a fluid column... you can just set the widths of each column. Unless I'm not understanding the question. The table layout will still work, just fix the width of the table to pixels instead of a percentage.

Comment: Sorry.  For large displays, I want #container at 960px.  I have media queries in the demo which change this to 95% at smaller screen widths.

Comment: I think you have the code to make this work at this point... the container width can be adjusted via media queries and the right column will fill the whole right side. You could even just give the container a `width:95%; max-width:960px;` and that should do it without additional media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to trigger other CSS rules depending on the viewport size.

This should do what you're asking for:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {

    #right { float: none; width: 100%; }

    #left { float: none; }


}
```

Comment: Thanks Nils.  Can you please see what happens below 970px here: http://www.doig.com.au/test/2/  The #right column is flowing around the #left column, breaking the divide, which I need to keep.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. You also have to remove the float from #left in the media query or the right column will wrap. I'll update my answer above to account for this.

Comment: I made this change.  See http://www.doig.com.au/test/2/  The divs are on separate lines.

Comment: Is this not how you want it to be?

Comment: No, I wanted it on the same line, thanks Nils.  Tim's answer above fixed it.